# Why I have no scaling_governor?

Tags: linux, centos, v8

I am running [v8's benchmark program](https://v8.dev/docs/benchmarks), and I run the following command

```
./tools/cpu.sh fast
```

It prints out

```
Setting CPU frequency governor to "ondemand"
./tools/cpu.sh: line 13: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: no such file or directory
```

And I run

```
# ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0
cache  crash_notes  crash_notes_size  microcode  node0  power  subsystem  topology  uevent
```

And find there is no "cpufreq"

After some searching, I find that I should install cpufrequtils, and I run

```
yum install cpufrequtils
```

After that, no thing works. So I wonder what is wrong here.

My system is

```
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.2 (Final)
Release:        7.2
Codename:       Final
```

And my cpuinfo is

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 94
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 61xx CPU
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x1
cpu MHz         : 2499.998
cache size      : 4096 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 1
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 1
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 arat
bogomips        : 4999.99
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your kernel configuration whether the governor interface is exposed at all, and which governors are available. I don't know any specifics about CentOS. On Debian/Ubuntu the governors should be available by default (last I checked, they were).

Maybe https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/power_management_guide/cpufreq_governors helps?